# Data types set a default value Laravel

Tags: php, sql, laravel

What is the correct syntax for declaring a default value on creating a column in laravel? I tried this but I get many errors. Can someone help me to find out what is the problem here?

[image]

This is the expected output of the table
[image]

```
  Schema::create('tbl_payroll_leave_schedulev2', function (Blueprint $table) {
                $table->increments('payroll_leave_schedule_id');
                $table->integer('payroll_leave_employee_id')->unsigned();
                $table->foreign("payroll_leave_employee_id")->references("payroll_leave_employee_id")->on("tbl_payroll_leave_employee_v2")->onDelete('cascade');
                $table->date('payroll_schedule_leave');
                $table->integer('shop_id');
                $table->time('leave_hours')->default(DB::raw('NOT NULL DEFAULT 00:00'));
                $table->tinyInteger('leave_whole_day')->default('1');
                $table->decimal('consume', 4, 2)->default('0.00');
                $table->string('notes',255);
```

Comment: Can you share those `many errors` ?

Comment: @user2486 i putted the picture of the error

Comment: @user2486 and i added the expected table of the schema.

Comment: by default, column will be `NOT NULL`, so just make your `leave_hours` column's default function to `00:00`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot set the `NOT NULL` with the `default` function. Columns are non nullable by default. The correct syntax for the `leave_hours` column would be like this:

```
$table->time('leave_hours')->default('00:00');
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to change line in your config/database.php file

`'strict' => true` to `'strict' => false`

OR use `useCurrent()`

```
$table->time('leave_hours')->useCurrent();
```

Comment: An additional step may be needed which is to comment the following middleware:
as shown in this thread
https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/laravel-54-auto-convert-empty-text-input-to-null